# Formatting hyperlink type field with file directory path

Tags: sharepoint-online, hyperlink, json-formatting, column-formatting

By default, a hyperlink type field in a SharePoint Online list looks like a regular field. It's not until you hover over the text that you actually see that it's a hyperlink.

I am trying to edit/format this field so it "pops" (i.e. underline and blue-color the font; shade the background, etc.).

I am able to achieve this by using a simple JSON script; however, it only works when the hyperlink is pointing to a web-based source (i.e. `google.com`).  Some of my items have a hyperlink that direct the user to a file directory instead (i.e. `//server_name/files/samplefile.docx`). For these type of hyperlinks, the JSON script simply blanks the field.

Any help?

#### Here is the list:

[image: List]

#### Here are the values for item 1:

[image: item1]

#### And the values for item 2:

[image]

And there is the JSON script being applied to the "Test" field:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField.desc",
  "style": {
    "color": "red",
    "font-weight": "bold"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "@currentField"
  }
}
```

Comment: You code seems fine. Just make sure you are passing complete document path like `https:// tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SPName/Shared%20Documents/Document.docx`

Comment: Thanks Ganesh.  The document is NOT located in a sharepoint library, instead, it lives in a different server.

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting is fine, but it appears that SharePoint Online is actively checking against `href` to make sure it begins with http, https, or mailto: within the JSON formatting.

> [You can't use column formatting to output links to protocols other than `http://`, `https://`, or `mailto:`.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#create-clickable-actions)

This is a recommended feature to add to SharePoint on their [uservoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/39525973-hyperlinks-for-file-protocols) platform.
If you've found a work around, please post here.  Even if you got the file protocol working, most modern browsers prevent those links from being opened, which would require an additional workaround.

If you were doing something similar with jslink previously, there is a guide for creating a [SharePoint Framework Extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/guidance/migrate-from-jslink-to-spfx-extensions).